# I removed all 32-bit binaries from Ubuntu 18.04 and it's causing issues

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, 64-bit, 32-bit

### Original question

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04, 64-bit, so I naively thought I could get rid of all the 32-bit binaries that existed on the system. I followed the instructions in [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/714391/how-do-i-remove-all-i386-architecture-packages-from-my-debian-installation), and everything seemed to work fine still.

However, it turns out that an app called [Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/about/) has some dependencies linked to these 32-bit binaries: `libgl1-mesa-dri:i386` and `libgl1:i386`, which each depend on yet another bunch of 32-bit binaries and so on.

Of course, I didn't make a back-up and so now I'm stuck with a broken Steam installation and potentially even more broken dependencies that I can't see. Is there a way to get them back?

### Additional information

#### Result of the `dpkg` command

This is following up on @nobody's comment:

```bsh
$ dpkg -l | egrep -v '^li|rc'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
+++-=============================================-================================================-============-============================================================================================================================================================
```

#### Problems while reinstalling steam

Steam attempts to reinstall the missing dependencies, but those dependencies also have missing dependencies:

```bsh
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1:i386
[sudo] password for jansthcirlu: 
...................................
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgl1:i386 : Depends: libglvnd0:i386 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglx0:i386 (= 1.0.0-2ubuntu2.3) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (>= 2.4.100) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-intel1:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (>= 2.4.66) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (>= 2.4.31) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.75) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libllvm10:i386 (>= 1:9~svn298832-1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
Press return to continue:
```

After pressing return to exit, I get the following error message:

[image: Steam missing 32-bit libraries]

Comment: The simplest method would like be to go to the Software Centre, uninstall Steam, then re-install it. This will re-trigger all those 32-bit libraries to be downloaded again.

Comment: If you install a Ubuntu 18.04 *amd64* or *x86_64* system, there will be no 32-bit binaries.  Where they exist, it's because you installed them, either directly or indirectly (ie. install `steam` will cause its dependencies to be installed).  Before you make assumptions, it's best to explore why a package was installed (ie. why was it there?).  Apt keeps logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log` could have been scanned), or you can use commands to look at why (`apt-cache rdepends` etc).  It's best to explore why before you *jump to a conclusion*... or have an adequate backup strategy

Comment: @guiverc you're right, I will be adding more details to my question after work with the relevant errors I get, it seems like this is a problem that's specific to my situation and not necessarily to anyone who deletes 32-bit binaries

Comment: `dpkg -l | egrep -v '^ii|rc'`  please also.

Comment: @nobody I've updated my question

Comment: @Matigo I have updated my question to include some screenshots, as you can see the dependencies are not reinstalled automatically

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text.](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/158442) Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @muru thanks, edited

Comment: You can just keep adding the required dependencies to your ```sudo apt install …``` line until it is happy. e.g. ```sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx0:i386``` and so on.

Comment: @grifferz unfortunately I couldn't download them either because they depended on other packages, but none of that matters anymore because I ended up upgrading to 20.04 and that fixed it